# Adding a SQL connection to my ASP.NET Core application - how to define ConnectionStrings

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am trying to connect my ASP.NET Core application to my database.

To do this I'm supposed to edit the appsettings.json file and define my default connection.

I am not sure what to put under Server and Database.

I am trying to connect the database StudentDB.

Here is what string I tried to use to connect to my database:

[image]

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=ACTKPTP115;Database=StudentsDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveRes ultSets=true;"
},
```

As you can see I connected the database in Visual Studio.

Here is the database I'm trying to connect in Microsoft SQL management studio:

[image]

What do I type in the ConnectionStrings under Server and Database to properly connect my server?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Can you try:

```
Server=ACTKPTP115\\SQLTEST;Database=StudentsDB;Trusted_Conn‌ection=True;Multiple‌​ActiveResultSets=tru‌​e;
```

Some resource from Microsoft about connection strings for ASP.NET Core:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Comment: That was it but it's actually "Server=ACTKPTP115\\SQLTEST;Database=StudentsDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing that mistake out. Edited the answer to reflect correctly for those who references it in the future. Have a good one!

Answer (score 19):

This piece of code worked for me:

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:xxUAT.domain.com,64609;Initial Catalog=IdentityDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=xx;Password=xx"
} }
```